# separate view from controller

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, model-view-controller

In order to respect the MVC pattern, I would like to dissociate the view from the controller.
For example

- QuestionView (inherits from UIVIew)
- QuestionViewController (inherits from UIViewController

In my controller, I set the view self.view = ...

But when I push a button in the view, it should call a method from the controller BUT the view shouldn't know its controller right ?

So how can I link the view to the controller ?

Comment: Create a delegate object in view class and while creating questionview set it as questionview.delegate = self;//(QuestionViewController object). Inside your view class use this delegate as all targets for buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Set button target as QuestionViewController's object programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

With iOS in most cases you can get the job done with only sub classing the controller part, and not the views. So you use the UIKit provided classes straight 'out of the box'.

It's is possible because:

- The layout: this can be stored in a Nib file and be loaded by the controller.
- responding to user events: the UIcontrols have generic callback mechanisms: delegates and actions. The 'connection' is either made in the nib file, or in the controller code.

Personally, I only subclass views when I need custom drawing.

So, the View INSTANCE obviously 'knows' its controller, but it is all done through generic interfaces, and so the view CODE is ignorant of your controller.